# Construct a polynomial of least degree possible with given information: real roots $-1$ (With multiplicity 2 and 1) and $(2,f(2))=(2,4)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A am to construct a polynomial with given information:

real roots $-1$ (With multiplicity 2 and 1) and $(2,f(2))=(2,4)$

The answer is: $f(x)=\frac{4}{9}(x^3+x^2-x-1)$

This is an extension exercise at the end of a book. In this particular case I don't even know how to get started or how to approach, I cannot see the bigger picture. For this reason I have not shown steps already taken or what I have tried already.

How can I arrive at $f(x)=\frac{4}{9}(x^3+x^2-x-1)$? Granular, baby steps greatly appreciated where possible.

Comment: You say "with multiplicity $2$ ande $1$", which suggests **two** roots are given. Did you mean the real roots to be $\pm 1$? Because by inspection both $+1$ and $-1$ are roots of the answer. In that case, the minimal polynomial is necessarily of the form $$f(x) = C(x-r_1)^{m_1}(x-r_2)^{m_2}$$ where the root $r_k$ has multiplicity $m_k$. You just have to find $C$ so that $f(2) = 4$.

Comment: Did you mean real roots $-1$ (with multiplicity $2$) and $1$?  In that case, $f(x) = a(x + 1)^2(x - 1)$, so $f(2) = a(2 + 1)^2(2 - 1) = 9a = 4 \implies a = 4/9$, so $f(x) = \frac{4}{9}(x + 1)^2(x - 1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to find a cubic polynomial. Let $$f(x)=A(x+1)^2(x+d)$$

where $d \ne 1$, $A \ne 0$.

When $x=2$, we have $4=9A(2+d)$

$$d=\frac{4}{9A}-2$$

$$f(x) = A(x+1)^2(x+\frac{4}{9A}-2)$$

Try to pick a suitable value of $A$ to get what you want.

---

Actually if we consider $f(x)=B(x+1)^2$, when $x=2$, we have $4=9B$ satisfy the condition unless I misinterpreted your question.

If the question says there is a root with multiplicity $2$ and another root with multiplicity $1$, then the polynomial is at least cubic.